# invalid conversions, unspecified behaviour and char arrays?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do http://www.spoj.com/problems/SHLIGHTS/, for which I have designed a solution. I am very new to C++(about 14 days), and I am facing a lot of problems. Earlier I used Python, and there was nothing of these errors, anyways, I wrote this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

//example is GBGBBB
//t=0, GBGBBB then t=1,BGBGBB then t=2 BBGBGB, then t=3 BBBGBG
//search for GB and replace it with BG

//we need a function that replaces things
string swapSEQ(string SEQ)
{
    unsigned int sizeSEQ=SEQ.size();
    unsigned int curr(0);
    while (curr<sizeSEQ-1)
    {
        if (SEQ[curr]=="G" and SEQ[curr+1]=="B")
        {
            SEQ[curr]="B";SEQ[curr+1]="G";curr+=2;
        }
        else {++curr;}
    }
    return SEQ;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int numCases;
    scanf("%d",&numCases);
//  cin>>numCases;
    for (unsigned int currentCase=0;currentCase<numCases;++currentCase)
    {
        string SEQ;
        //scanf("%s",&SEQ);
        cin>>SEQ;
        string swapped=swapSEQ(SEQ);
        unsigned long long t=0;
        while (swapped!=SEQ)
        {
            swapped=swapSEQ(SEQ);++t;       
        }
        printf("%lld\n",t);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that's a lot of details, but that's it. SPOJ shows blank lines after inputs and outputs, but after reading the description, I understand we have to do things in single lines. Here's what I get with my g++4.7 compiler(LINUX)

```
SHLIGHTS.cpp: In function ‘std::string swapSEQ(std::string)’:
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:18: error: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Werror=address]
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:18: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:37: error: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Werror=address]
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:37: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:52: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
SHLIGHTS.cpp:17:66: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

**What is happening? There's something about pointers, const char* and unspecified behaviour.
**I know pointers are sort of variables that point to memory locations, nothing more.
**I've used scanf at some places and cin at others(if I replace scanf by cin, I get the same errors)
**Is it something about the fact that I returned a string that took as argument?
**Where did I use a pointer?
**Am I wrong about this- strings in c++ are char arrays? If no, then where is the invalid conversion?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for anything wrong. If it's too long, please answer any of the doubts.

Comment: if (SEQ[curr]=="G" and SEQ[curr]=="B") - how do you expect this to ever be true? - and - SEQ[curr]="B";SEQ[curr]="G" - set character to B and then to G, why?? (also should be 'B' and 'G' not "B" and "G" of course).

Comment: (What I meant was, how can the character at position 'curr' possibly be both G and B at the same time?)

Comment: @davmac Sorry, I noticed that. Reading the question I guess OP forgot some `+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `'G'` instead of `"G"` and so on. When you access a char array (e.g. `arr[5]`) you obtain a `char`, which you can compare with a char literal (being: `'G'`) and not with a cstring (e.g. `"G"` or `"Google"`).

The compiler is your friend, it points out that the problem is:

> comparison with string literal

Comment: And of course, Python doesn't make this distinction.  Python doesn't have a character type, and indexing into a string in Python returns a one character string.

Comment: @JamesKanze you again :)

Comment: @StefanoFalasca He can mark your answer as selected, which he did, but not close the question. That's a different thing. Questions are only closed when they are found unsuitable for this forum for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to compare `SEQ[curr]` with `'G'` not `"G"` since it's a char and not a string.
2. You should use operator `&&` instead of `and`.
3. Something with your logic is worng. At one index of a string you can have only 1 char. So writing `if (SEQ[curr] == 'G' && SEQ[curr] == 'B'` is same as writing `if (false)`.
4. It is not an error, but please don't abuse your code by writing more than one commend at a line.
5. If you writing is *C++* please use `cin` , not `scanf`.
6. Why are you creating `sizeSEQ` if you never use it? Don't!

Comment: i changed the curr to curr+1

Comment: To support @StefanoFalasca's comment, §2.6/2 in the Standard states that `and` behaves exactly the same as `&&`. Though I agree that `&&` is more usual in C++ code and this part of the Standard is not so widely known.